# Get number from non numeric text input string without having to break form behaviour

Tags: javascript, textinput

I have an input where I will parse a number out of the text (has commas ect) when sending to the form. What is the easiest way to do this? Do I have to break the normal form submit behaviour and get the number out with a js function?

Adobe flex had a concept of  an itemRenderer, which would render the value differently than an itemEditor, but I am not aware of an equivalent in HTML.

Comment: You could get it out on `input` but yeah, you would need javascript somewhere down the line - what does this mean though? `when sending to the form`

Comment: pressing submit, whats with the random downvotes on this site.

Comment: The downvotes are there because your question does not meet the standards described in [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @trincot shesh kebabs https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.kk512na52

Comment: @SuperUberDuper just ask a good question within the community guidlines... or I guess you could just not and post that hackernoon article instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to stop the form from sending.

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var numbers = e.querySelector('input').value.match(/\d+/g);
  // Do with numbers whatever you want
  // If you want to send it to the server, do it by Ajax request
  return false;
})
```

Comment: yeah but I'm kinda breaking the default form behaviour then.

Comment: I wrote: "Do I have to break the normal form submit behaviour and get the number out with a js function?" The answer is yes, you have to break normal form behavior, because the normal behavior is designed for non JS sites.